# Format div around actual text height

Tags: html, css, themes, tumblr

I am trying to create a tumblr theme, and I am currently making the quotes. I want to have a large open quote to start, and I have that working, but if you change the font, the position of the open quote moves. Is there a way to confine the div to the actual height of the quote mark? (Live theme is here)
Javascript is ok, but I would prefer a pure html/css solution if possible.

Thanks in advance,
-tlf

Comment: Why don't you create a picture with the quote and display that in the div?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not totally sure what you're going for, but it sounds like the best option is to put the quote mark in `:before` and `:after` sudo-elements positioned against the actual height of your quote. Here's an example:

```
blockquote {
    position: relative;
    padding: 0 40px;
}
blockquote:before,
blockquote:after {
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    font-size: 80px;
    color: #c44;
}
blockquote:before {
    content: '\201C';
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
}
blockquote:after {
    content: '\201D';
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
    line-height: 0;
}
```